# How to add conditional transitions?

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg

This question is about transitions with d3.js, e.g. the change of the x attribute of a rectangle.

If you want the change to occur immediately you may set `delay = duration = 0` as in

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
   .transition()
   .delay(delay)
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("x", 0)
```

but this may be too expensive (assuming that transitions are more CPU consumpting than immediate changes). So how can I add the transition conditionally, behaving like

```
if (delay == 0 && duration == 0) {
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
} else {
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .transition()
        .delay(delay)
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("x", 0)
}
```

but less redundant and more compact, somehow like `x = condition ? 0 : 1`?

Answer (score 6):

This is a very strange situation, and I cannot think about a use case where it would be useful. That being said, here is one out of many possible solutions: extend the D3 selection prototype.

In my approach, we'll extend the prototype to return the exact same selection in case of both `delay` and `duration` are zero, or return a *transition* selection based on the current selection if they're not zero:

```
d3.selection.prototype.conditionalTransition =
  function(cond1, cond2) {
    return cond1 && cond2 ? this.transition().duration(duration).delay(delay) : this;
  };
```

Then, you just continue the chain of `attr()` methods:

```
d3.selectAll("rect")
  .conditionalTransition(delay, duration)
  .attr("x", 200);
```

Finally, pay attention to the fact that regular selections and transition selections have different methods with the same name, like `selection.on()` and `transition.on()`.

Here is the first demo. All the rects are in `x = 10`. The selection is turned into a transition selection:

```js
d3.selection.prototype.conditionalTransition =
  function(cond1, cond2) {
    return cond1 && cond2 ? this.transition().duration(duration).delay(delay) : this;
  };

const rect = d3.selectAll("rect");

const delay = 100,
  duration = 1000;

rect.conditionalTransition(delay, duration)
  .attr("x", 200)

function transitioning(sel) {
  return sel.transition()
    .delay(delay)
    .duration(duration);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
 <rect x="10" y="40" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
 <rect x="10" y="70" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
 <rect x="10" y="100" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
</svg>
```

And here is the same code, with both `delay` and `duration` equal to zero. As you can see the rectangles are already in the final position, there is no transition:

```js
d3.selection.prototype.conditionalTransition =
  function(cond1, cond2) {
    return cond1 && cond2 ? this.transition().duration(duration).delay(delay) : this;
  };

const rect = d3.selectAll("rect");

const delay = 0,
  duration = 0;

rect.conditionalTransition(delay, duration)
  .attr("x", 200)

function transitioning(sel) {
  return sel.transition()
    .delay(delay)
    .duration(duration);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
 <rect x="10" y="40" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
 <rect x="10" y="70" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
 <rect x="10" y="100" width="50" height="20" fill="teal"></rect>
</svg>
```